# Issues with Login form poping up when the webpage is loaded showing behind the contents on my webpage

Tags: html, css, forms, button, modal-dialog

Hi Guys I am new to web development, 

I have a logging button which is linked to a login form on my webpages. When the webpage is loaded my logging form pops up and appears behind the contents of my webpage without the button being clicked.

I have used `z-index=4000;` in CSS to bring it in front of the contents, but I am not sure if that is the right way of doing it. 
However the form still appears automatically when the webpage is loaded which shouldn't occur unless the logging button is clicked otherwise.

- Another small issue I have is my signup button doesn't line up next to the login button in the top nav section. It appears on the right side somehow.
  Below I am going to provide CSS and HTML of what I have so far.

I have spend days on this issue and i cant figure out what causes this issue , Your help will be highly important towards fixing this issue.  Many thanks.

```css
/* ------  top bar ------- */
   

 .topbar{
    background-color:#000;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5000;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
 top:0; 
}

nav {
  float:right;
  }


.btn.login{
    color:#fff;  
}

.btn.signup {
    color:#fff;
}

    /*------End Top bar------ */




    /*------------login area ---------*/
   
    #loginModal{display:none;}

    .loginbox{
        width: 320px;
        height: 380px;
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        top: 60%;
        left: 50%;
        position:fixed;
        transform: translate(-40%,-50%);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 60px 25px ;
     border:dotted #049CD9;
     border-radius: 20%;
     
     
    }

    .avatar{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -50px;
        left: calc(50% - 50px);
    }

    h1{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 0 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    .loginbox p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .loginbox input{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .loginbox input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
    {
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        background: transparent;
        outline: none;
        height: 40px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .loginbox input[type="submit"]
    {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        height: 40px;
        background: #008EF5;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 18px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #fb2525;
        color: #000;
    }
    .loginbox a{
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: darkgrey;
    }

    .loginbox a:hover
    {
        color: #ffc107;
    }

    /*------------End  login area ---------*/






    /*------- section one -------*/
    .section1-bg{
     background:url(../images/s1bg.jpg);
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
     padding-bottom: 30px;
     padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .text-center h3{
     font: 'Berkshire Swash', Helvetica, sans-serif;
     color: #2b2b2b;
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px blue, 8px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
     font-size: 50px;
     font-weight: bold;
        position:relative;
        top: -10px;
    }

    .text-center img{
       position:relative;
       top: -25px;
    }

    .text-center p{
     font-weight:300;
     font-size:25px;
     color:black;
    }

    .btn-md .booking-links{
     font-size: 1.2rem; 
     color: white;
     border: 2px solid green;
     border-radius: 25%; 
     padding: 15px 20px;
     background-color:#078D75;
     -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
        transition-duration: 0.4s; 
    }

    .btn-md .booking-links:hover {
      background-color: #368E41;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }


    .btn-md .gallery-links{
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     color: white;
     border: 2px solid green;
     border-radius: 25%;
     padding: 15px 20px;
     background-color:#037BDB;
     -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
        transition-duration: 0.1s; 
    }

    .btn-md .gallery-links:hover {
      background-color: #008CBA;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    /*------- section one -------*/
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en"><head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <title>Clypsdra Barber</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     
     <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
     <!-- awesome-font CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
     
         
      </head>
      <body>


  <header class="topbar">  
     <nav>

   <button href="" class="btn login btn-default d-inline-flex" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" ><i class="fa fa-sign-in"  style="font-size:24px" value="LOGIN" onclick="BtnPushed()" ></i> Login</button>  

   <button href="" class=" btn signup d-inline-flex" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupModal"><i class="fa fa-user"  style="font-size:24px" ></i>   Sign Up</button>      

    </nav>
 </header>



           
  <div class="loginbox" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
 
      <h1>Sign in</h1>
   <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter username" required>
    <p>Password</p>
       <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter password" required>
    <input type="submit" name=""  value="Login">
    <a href="#">Not a member?</a> <br>
    
   </form>
  
  </div>
       
        
        
        
        <!-- section one content -->
      <div style="box-shadow:1px 1px 100px black" class="section1-bg" id="testing"> 
       <div class="text-center">
      <img style="max-width:80%; border-radius:20%; border:4px outset black;box-shadow:8px 10px 10px blue" src="images/logoblue.png" height="auto" width="200px" class="mt-5">
       <h3 class="display-1 mb-0 responsive-headers">Clypsydra Barbershop</h3>
       <p>Quality Cuts with Premium Class</p>
       <button type="button" class="btn  btn-md "><a class="booking-links" href="booking.php">Booking</a></button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-md  "><a class="gallery-links" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></button>
       </div>
       </div>
      <!-- End section one content -->
        
        
        
        
        
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
       <script>
    
    var LogModal = document.getElementById = 'LoginModal';
           LogModal.setAttribute('display','none');
    var Btn = document.getElementsByClassName = 'btn';

        function BtnPushed(e){
                  Btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
                    LogModal.setAttribute('dispaly','true');  
                                                          })
                             }
     </script>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it right.
 Because the position of `#loginModal` is fixed, the `.text-center` parent must 
be positioned relative with z-index of -1.

[LIVE DEMO](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=94e2ebec-1029-4560-9d13-d7104acd0ae5)

```
.text-center{
position:relative;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Another mistake is `.topbar` is set to 5000 replace with:

```
 .topbar{
        z-index: 300;
        }
```

Replace the a tag with a button and call `showModal()` JS function to change the `#loginModal` display from 'none' to 'block':

```
<input type="button" style="float:right;margin-top:5px;margin-right:5px;" value="LOGIN" onClick="showModal()"/>

function showModal()
{
  document.getElementById("loginModal").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: But playing with z-index doesn't resolve the whole problem  as i have done, the Login form still pops up when the page is loaded which it shouldn't do until the login button is clicked. how can that be fixed

Comment: @charly `.topbar` z-index is set to 5000 change it to 300 or something, I have updated the demo link

Comment: when you set .topbar  zindex=300;  it stops the button from functioning. as mentioned, the main problem is the Login form pops up when the page is loaded. it should only appear when the login button is clicked.  playing with z-index doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @charly please check the link again, now i have added javascript function to change the display - `showModal()` function. and also it is better to use a button than a <a> tag is that answers your question? also the sign up button is aligned now.

Comment: <a> looks better than button that is why i used it.  also please ignore the java script i had in my code its nothing to do with the login button and form , i already  edited and removed it here.  i have checked the link.  the button opens the form but it doesn't close it when clicked .

Comment: you can design the button as you wish - use CSS for that, also when you want to close the form change the display again to none, the general idea is shown in the example.

Comment: i would like to choose <a> instead  if that is not an issue,  How move the sign up next to the login button?